# Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 fails

Tags: visual-studio-2012

[image]

Downloaded ISO and verified the hash. Installed Web Deploy 3.5 separately and Preperations.exe file is present in the "packages" directory..

After several tries, I even cleaned up "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache" directory, but nothing helps..

I'm going to uninstall Web Deploy 3.5 and try it again.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uninstalling the Web Deploy 3.5, I got the error as shown in the screenshot.

Steps I've taken to fix this:

1. Downloaded Update 4 ISO from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=327544
2. Manually uninstalled Web Deploy 3.5
3. Ran VS2012 repair using the command-line (couldn't do it via Add/Remove Programs): vs_premium.exe /repair
4. Had to run the repair twice as it failed the first time
5. Ran Update 4 installer and it failed with following error:

*[19A8:1FD0][2013-12-17T09:47:13]: Acquiring package: Preparation, payload: Preparation, copy from: C:\Users\Ostati\Desktop\Temp\VS2012.4\packages\Preparation.exe
[10C4:1550][2013-12-17T09:47:13]: Verified acquired payload: Preparation at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\Preparation, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\C6B63A9C9DFE6A89D63665FB41EFDD35689A78AD\packages\Preparation.exe.
[10C4:1550][2013-12-17T09:47:13]: Error 0x80070002: Failed to move verified file to complete payload path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\C6B63A9C9DFE6A89D63665FB41EFDD35689A78AD\packages\Preparation.exe
[10C4:1550][2013-12-17T09:47:13]: Error 0x80070002: Failed to cache payload: Preparation
[19A8:1FD0][2013-12-17T09:47:13]: MUX:  Verify Failed.  Retry acquiring, Retry Count: 1 of 3*

6. Manually Copied C:\Users\Ostati\Desktop\Temp\VS2012.4\packages" to C:\ProgramData\Package
   Cache\C6B63A9C9DFE6A89D63665FB41EFDD35689A78AD\"
7. Ran Update 4 again and it worked!**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when installing update 4, and found the following error message in the log file.

> [2B50:1FF0][2014-05-12T11:21:37]: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package
>   (webdeploy_x64_en_usmsi_902) failed: Error Message Id: 30002
>   ErrorMessage: Installing some features of Microsoft Web Deploy 3.5 is
>   not supported when using Shared Configuration for IIS. Please disable
>   Shared Configuration before installing these features ("IIS 7.0
>   Deployment Handler", "IIS Manager UI Module").

It seems that you can't install the update while you've got a shared configuration enabled.

I fixed this by disabling my shared configuration, then repairing the update, then re-enabling the shared configuration.